# Usage of "unless"

Tags: word-usage

I have found a restriction on the use of "unless" which was difficult to explain to my students (advanced ESL).

The student's sentence was:

*I would have had to go to the bank unless you had lent me the money.*

Several others produced similar sentences. How can we explain the difference in acceptability between:

- They'll kill her unless she gives them the money.
- *They would have killed her unless she gave them the money.
- They wouldn't have robbed her unless they were really poor.

Comment: The student's sentence is confusing because one might go to the bank *if* one gets the money (to put it in the bank) or if one doesn't get the money (to try to borrow money from the bank).  But, assuming it's the latter, normally one would expect to see *"I would **not** have had to go to the bank **if** you had lent me the money."* or *"I will **have** to go to the bank unless you **lend** me the money"*

Comment: Or (to follow OP's wording more closely) "I would have had to go to the bank *if you hadn't* lent me the money."  Just an 'of the top of my head' thought: is "unless" more commonly used in a *future* sense than when referring to *past* events?

Comment: I'm not going to try to explain the syntactic differences, but the use of *unless* in the way you describe is typical of an illiterate rural US vernacular.

Comment: Their sentence looks perfectly fine to me. Shrugs.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are forms of the restriction described rather laconically by [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as) as "We don’t use unless for impossible conditions". I would say it as "only use 'unless' for a condition where you know whether or not it obtains".

So it works in the future, and your third example shows that it works in the past when the condition is an unknown; but not in the common case when we are talking hypotheticals but we actually know what happened: then we can only use "if ... not".

Comment: Thanks. That was my feeling about it too but I wanted someone to confirm it!

Answer (score 1):

In the grammatical cases, "unless (S)" is equivalent to "if (not (S))".  In the ungrammatical cases, instead, the supposed equivalence would have to be to "if (perfect (not (S)))".  That is, the problem is that "not" is not in the immediate scope of "if", because perfect "have" intervenes between "if" and "not".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I'm only a lowly language centre teacher, not a linguist, and I don't fully understand it. Can you recommend a textbook that explains this type of analysis? Thanks.

Comment: McCawley's **The Syntactic Phenomena of English** is very good.  I just looked for discussion of "if not"="unless" in this and found that McCawley does not agree with what I said.  It's here: https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA626&dq=mccawley+phenomena+unless+%22if+not%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8zcK0i5_NAhVEpB4KHe-YDU8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=mccawley%20phenomena%20unless%20%22if%20not%22&f=false